# Best Software For Automated Database Backup (MySQL and MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, mysql, backup, database, automated

What is the best software that can backup mysql and ms sql databases automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a single software package that can do both?  You may want to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely (for linux) `automysqlbackup` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/.

For windows mysql server you can use the scheduled backup tool from mysql administrator application.

For MS SQL I use SQL script executed from scheduled tasks. [Here is a good one](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1070).

To upload automatically remotely (from windows) on a FTP server you can use [Fling](http://www.nchsoftware.com/fling/index.html).

Comment: The user asks for the best, which likely is a high priced backup package. Granted, poor wording of the question, but then this is the posters responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the Enterprise backup applications can handle this.  Legato, CommVault, Backup Exec, etc.  They can backup MySQL, MSSQL, Windows, Linux, etc.  All it takes it buying the correct plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, I wrote a shell script to weekly full backup and daily incremental backup to a FTP server.

PS: Can you define "best"?

Comment: I also do scripts but my boss told me that we should have a centralized backup plan for us to administer backups easily.

Comment: What I mean of the word "best" is like most recommended.

Answer (score 0):

For MSSQL, a SQL Agent job can do that for you. It's built right into the SQL Server installation.